# i need to get the time work for each employee

Tags: c#, ms-access, error-handling

I have an access database storing the times when each employee came to work and the time when the employee left. I would like to calculate home much time the user spent working. Here's my code:

```
    DataTable dm = new DataTable();
    today = DateTime.Today;
    hooodorDa = new OleDbDataAdapter("select heUsers,heCome,heGo from HoodoorEnseraf where heDate=#" + today.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "# and  heUsers='" + heUsers.Text + "' ", connection);
    hooodorDa.Fill(dm);
    DateTime hec = Convert.ToDateTime(dm.Rows[0]["heCome"]);
    DateTime heg = Convert.ToDateTime(dm.Rows[0]["heGo"]);
    TimeSpan diff = hec - heg;
    command = new OleDbCommand("update  HoodoorEnseraf set heDifference=? where heUsers=? ;", connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", diff);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", heUsers.Text);
```

I need to insert the value in number field, as illustrated in the screenshot below, but my code is giving me an error:

> object cannot cast from dbnull to other types

What's wrong with my code?

[image]

Comment: What is your problem? I mean, it's nice you put code here what you have tried so far, but explaining what your problems are with the code you have posted would probably bring more response to your question

Comment: What is the problem there? Is the diff value correct?

Comment: no i receive this error (object cannot cast from dbnull to other types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for the [`TimeSpan.TotalMinutes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalminutes(v=vs.110).aspx) property. Your `heDifference` is a number, so you can get the total amount of minutes the user has worked and store that there.
You could use [`TimeSpan.TotalHours`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours(v=vs.110).aspx), however minutes is more accurate.

Corrected code:

```
DataTable dm = new DataTable();
today = DateTime.Today;
hooodorDa = new OleDbDataAdapter("select heUsers,heCome,heGo from HoodoorEnseraf where heDate=#" + today.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "# and  heUsers='" + heUsers.Text + "' ", connection);
hooodorDa.Fill(dm);
DateTime hec = dm.Rows[0].Field<DateTime>("heCome");
DateTime heg = dm.Rows[0].Field<DateTime>("heGo");
TimeSpan diff = hec - heg;
command = new OleDbCommand("update  HoodoorEnseraf set heDifference=" +
    diff.TotalMinutes.ToString() + " where heUsers='" + heUsers.Text + "';", connection);
```

Comment: *"however minutes is more accurate"* - why is that?

Comment: @Sinatr OP wants to know how long an employee has worked - so minutes would be a more accurate representation of the amount of time they've worked on a given day. Seconds would be even more accurate if required, although minutes would do.

Comment: Both properties are `double`. Why `1.5` hours would be less accurate than `90.0` minutes?

Comment: @Sinatr I didn't mean the property - the DB field is an integer, so it can't hold 1.5

Comment: how i use it in my code please help

Comment: @AymanShokri `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", diff.TotalMinutes);`

Comment: same problem object cannot cast from dbnull to other types

Comment: @AymanShokri That was a problem with getting the DateTime value. Use the code I've posted and check your database table that the record doesn't have any null values in the DateTime fields.